# font appearing SUPER thin on Safari/iOS

Tags: css, ios, material-ui, next.js, webfonts

I'm at a loss on this, as I've checked *all* of the recommendations for fixing the super-thin fonts on Safari/iOS but nothing is working.

The difference:
[image: Font difference on Safari]

https://krista-doubleday--preview-apq5vrih.web.app/

the _document.js:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/core'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheets();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: App => props => sheet.collect(<App {...props} />)
      });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        )
      }
    } finally {
      ctx.renderPage(sheet)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
          <link rel="preload" as="font" href="./fonts/architectsdaughter-regular-webfont.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous" />
          <link rel="preload" as="font" href="./fonts/raleway-variablefont_wght-webfont.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous" />
          <link rel="preload" as="font" href="./fonts/architectsdaughter-regular-webfont.woff" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" />
          <link rel="preload" as="font" href="./fonts/raleway-variablefont_wght-webfont.woff" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png" />
          <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest" />
          <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#d8a990" />
          <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ecd5c9" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

The global.css file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Architects Daughter";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  // unicode-range: U+000-5FF;
  src: local("Architects Daughter"),
    url("/fonts/architectsdaughter-regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("/fonts/architectsdaughter-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Raleway";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: optional;
  src: local("Raleway"),
    url("/fonts/raleway-variablefont_wght-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("/fonts/raleway-variablefont_wght-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;

  & img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  & p,
  li {
    max-width: 75ch;
    margin: auto !important;
    orphans: 4;
    widows: 4;
    font-family: Raleway Thin, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Helvetica,
      Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans,
      Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
    font-family: Raleway;
    text-align: justify;
    font-style: normal;
  }
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Architects Daughter", cursive;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
}

.main a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #d2a876;
  text-decoration-thickness: 3px;
  transition: color 300ms ease-in-out;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.animated {
  & img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

.framed {
  display: block;
  border: 2vmin solid #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0.5vw 0.5vh 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.geometric {
  background-image: url("/images/geometric.png");
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.inset {
  position: relative;

  & ::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 2%;
    left: 2%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 15%;
    border-top: 1vw solid white;
    border-left: 1vw solid white;
  }

  & ::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 2%;
    right: 2%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 15%;
    border-bottom: 1vw solid white;
    border-right: 1vw solid white;
  }
}

.keep-wide {
  min-width: 1210px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  p:not(.no-float)::before {
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 35vw;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .keep-wide {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    text-align: justify;

    & img,
    picture {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      float: none;
      margin: inherit none;
      border-radius: 0px !important;
    }
  }

  .no-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

the Mui theme file:

```
import { createMuiTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
let theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: ['Raleway', '-apple-system', 'BlinkMacSystemFont', 'Helvetica', '"Segoe UI"',
    'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', '"Fira Sans"', '"Droid Sans"', '"Helvetica Neue"',
      'sans-serif'].join(' '),
    lineHeight: '2rem',
    fontWeight: 'normal'
  },
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#edc5c9'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#c0debb'
    },
    ivory: {
      main: '#f7f2ec'
    },
    salmon: {
      main: '#ebc1ba'
    },
    mint: {
      main: '#c0debb',
      light: '#dcf3d8'
    },
    lightGreen: {
      main: '#ceddcc'
    },
    vanilla: {
      main: '#f1ead7'
    },
    lavender: {
      main: '#bfaab9'
    },
    sienna: {
      main: '#ecd5c9'
    },
    lightblue: {
      main: '#bfd8dc'
    }
  },
  components: {
    MuiTypography: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          fontFamily: ['Raleway', '-apple-system', 'BlinkMacSystemFont', 'Helvetica', '"Segoe UI"',
            'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', '"Fira Sans"', '"Droid Sans"', '"Helvetica Neue"',
            'sans-serif'].join(' '),
          fontStyle: 'normal',
          fontWeight: 'normal'
        },
        h1: {
          color: "#555555",
          fontWeight: "400"
        },
        h2: {
          color: "#555555",
          fontWeight: "400"
        },
        h3: {
          color: "#555555",
          fontWeight: "400"
        },
        body1: {
          fontSize: '1.2rem',
          lineHeight: '2rem',
          fontWeight: '400'
        },
        body2: {
          fontSize: '1.2rem',
          lineHeight: '2rem',
          fontWeight: '400'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

export default theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme)
```

On Chrome/Firefox etc. it works just fine, but on iOS/Safari the font is SUPER (unreadable) font. I've tried setting the font-style to normal. I've set `-webkit-font-smoothing` to `antialiased-subpixel`. The interesting part is this: When I go to fonts.google.com, the font I'm using (Raleway) works just fine on Safari/iOS. I even used the inspector to see if there's something that they're doing that I'm not. I'm not sure if it is a setting in Material-UI that's messing things up, but for whatever reason, it's not working on my build. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Raleway is a very thin font, so try a larger `font-weight`. When you specify `normal`, this translates into `400`. Setting it to something like `700` should be better.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Raleway";
  font-weight: 700; // <-- here!
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: optional;
  src: local("Raleway"),
    url("/fonts/raleway-variablefont_wght-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("/fonts/raleway-variablefont_wght-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}
```

| `400` | `700` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Very light font] | [image: Much more readable font] |

*Tested on Chrome*

Comment: The problem is I like the way it looks on every other browser, though. I

Comment: @JoelHager hmm ok. Btw the first time you open the page, the Raleway font isn't getting applied. You need to refresh it. That might have something to do with the problem.

Comment: I may have messed it up by trying another 'fix'. FontSquirrel didn't have the . preceding the font file location. I added it in response to another thread here, but it doesn't seem to fix anything.